# What's the maximum amount of RAM I can use in a Windows box?

Tags: windows, memory, .net-2.0, 64-bit, hardware

Obviously, that's 64-bit windows.

Also, what's the maximum amount of memory a single 64-bit process can use?
I was kind of counting on using it all... 
(Yes, I know what I'm doing, please don't tell me that if I need that much RAM i must be doing something wrong)

Also, is this the same for a .Net 2.0 process? Or is there a lower limit for .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758523.aspx
  - Windows Server 2003, 64 bit Datacenter Edition supports physical memory up to 512GB

A single process should be able to use most of it, some will be used by the OS.

The answer from Re0sless is better then mine. The limit is now 2TB, in Datacenter SP2, and 2008.

Answer (score 6):

What version of windows? it differs from XP to vista and from home to business versions of vista, and I would guess again for server.

see [here for more info on maximum ram for diffrent windows versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx)

for Windows Server 2008 Datacenter MS quote 2 TB of physical memory.

Answer (score 5):

## [Link](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx)

[image: 64 processors 2tb ram]

Comment: that equates to 1.95tb of memory for those who are curious (like i was)

Comment: And a WTF: 166 MB of the kernel are paged.

Answer (score 1):

We run Windows boxes with 16 gigs of memory, but that is because we are running multiple VM Ware instances, I presume you mean in a single instance. On Vista it depends upon the edition. It breaks out like this:

> **Vista Basic:** 8 GB
>   **Vista Home Premium:** 16 GB
>   **Vista Business/Enterprise/Ultimate:** 128+ GB

Answer (score 0):

Something we found out recently: with MySQL running on Win32, you can only use up to 2GB per process. On Win64, the memory is not managed as well and a single MySQL instance will run your memory into the ground. Ours used up all 16GB we have. So regarding how much memory 1 64-bit process can use: the answer is however much the OS allows.

Answer (score 0):

[According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_editions#Advantages) you can have 128 GB of physical RAM in a 64-bit Windows XP computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows Server machine.

As for which edition (Datacenter, Enterprise, etc)... Whatever it takes to give my little .Net Process as much memory as it can.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Linux. You will not have any of these issues and you will get better performance.